# HttpClient post produces wrong headers and no body

Tags: c#, api, http

I am trying to get data from my api using this code:

```
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters), UTF8Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content);
```

Unfortunately when I am trying to debug this request with Fiddler it produces this raw request.

```
OPTIONS https://localhost:7052/v1/users/login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:7052
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Origin: https://localhost:7063
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36 Edg/100.0.1185.44
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://localhost:7063/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pl,en;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7
```

Proper should be:

```
POST https://localhost:7052/v1/users/login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:7052
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 50
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="100", "Microsoft Edge";v="100"
accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36 Edg/100.0.1185.44
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Origin: https://localhost:7052
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://localhost:7052/swagger/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pl,en;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7

{
  "username": "string",
  "password": "string"
}
```

I am struggling with this problem and maybe I am missing something obvious?

Edit:
I had an misconfigured CORS. Thank you Panagiotis Kanavos for pointing me in the right direction.

In my minimal api project I had to configure CORS policy

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
       .AllowAnyHeader()
       .AllowAnyMethod()
));
```

before

```
app.UseCors();
```

Comment: What kind of application is this? Blazor? Are you using CORS? That's the pre-flight request sent to the server asking whether a POST is allowed. The POST should appear after that. Check [How CORS works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#how-cors-works), especially the `Preflight Requests` section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Agent string suggests you're using Blazor and send a request to a site using CORS. The `OPTIONS` request is [a CORS pre-flight request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#how-cors-works) and is entirely normal. The browser is asking the server if it's OK to make a POST request.

If you use your browser's developer tools you'll see the POST request right after the OPTIONS request.

As the docs explain :

> For some CORS requests, the browser sends an additional request, called a "preflight request", before it sends the actual request for the resource.
>
> The browser can skip the preflight request if the following conditions are true:
>
> - The request method is GET, HEAD, or POST, **and**
> - The application does not set any request headers other than Accept, Accept-Language, Content-Language, Content-Type, or Last-Event-ID, **and**
> - The Content-Type header (if set) is one of the following:
>
>   - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   - multipart/form-data
>   - text/plain

You're sending a JSON string so there's no way to avoid the preflight request.

In .NET 6 you can use [PostAsJsonAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.postasjsonasync?view=net-6.0) and get rid of most of your code, but not the OPTIONS request.

Since .NET 6 is the current LTS version, you should migrate to it sooner or later. .NET 5 [goes out of support](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-5-end-of-support-update/) in 3 weeks.